# Doxygen does not show Namespaces tab in document although show is YES

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen for sometime. I previously generated a documentation for my source code with namespaces. It was working OK. But now I created a new project for my new sources and Doxygen does not put Namespaces tab to the documents although SHOW_NAMESPACES is YES and there are lots of namespaces in the source code. The namespace of classes are seen when selected but I dont have the tab.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

You either need to give the namespaces some documentation or set EXTRACT_ALL to YES.

Example:

```
$ mkdir test-dir
$ cd test-dir
$ echo 'namespace test {}' > test.hpp
$ doxygen -g  # generate default config file
(output)
$ grep -P '^(EXTRACT_ALL|SHOW_NAMESPACES)' Doxyfile  # show default settings
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
$ doxygen     # generate docs
(output)
```

Now open html/index.html, there *won't* be a namespace tab.  This is what you're seeing.

```
$ sed -i '/^EXTRACT_ALL/s/NO/YES/' Doxyfile  # change setting
$ grep -P '^(EXTRACT_ALL|SHOW_NAMESPACES)' Doxyfile  # show change
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
$ doxygen
(output)
```

Now open html/index.html, there *will* be a namespace tab.

Tested with doxygen 1.6.3.